# SharePoint "Group By" is broken when using "Allow Multiple Values" for a column

Tags: sharepoint

I want to show the documents in my document library grouped by category. The category is a lookup column that I added that allows for multiple values. Unfortunately this breaks the "group by"-functionality completely. Is there a programmatic solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is one way... It's complex and ugly - but it should work :)

It is possible for you to write you own view for at list (HTML, JavaScript and all). The VWSTYLES.xml file in the C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML folder, contains the HTML and JavaScript for the default SharePoint view styles - getting your inspiration from this, you can create your own view style, where you can do anything you want!

The problem is, that SharePoint don't have any way to deploy your custom view style - this is where the ugly part comes in - you have two options for deploying your view style.

1. Add you code directly to the VWSTYLE.xml/Edit a copy of it and override it with a feature

   Pros:

   > You will still be able to edit the
   >   view from the SharePoint interface

   Cons:

   > You override a default SharePoint
   >   file - your work can be overridden by
   >   a SharePoint update.
   >
   > Your view style will be available on every list in SharePoint.
2. Create your view programmatically on the list

   Pros:

   > You don't override any default
   >   SharePoint files.
   >
   > You can control which list uses your
   >   view

   Cons:

   > You wont be able to edit the view thru the SharePoint interface

I've used method 2 a couple of times myself - and it works... but it's not pretty! :)

Comment: Could you explain more about how to "create your view programmatically on the list?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. When grouping items/documents, you display them in different groups based on a grouping value. I don't think SharePoint has support for adding a single item to multiple groups. With multiple values in the grouping field its' impossible to know which group to add the item/document to. I am not sure if this is an error or if it's by design.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas is correct, this is by design as the item would have to appear multiple times in different groups. It is worth noting that this is possible via the web services, however.

See [why I was getting duplicate rows from the sharepoint lists web service](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/06/10/why-i-was-getting-duplicate-rows-from-the-sharepoint-lists-web-service/)

And no, I've no idea why the lists webservice will do it, but the API won't.

Comment: http://andrewwburns.com/2008/04/07/duplicate-rows-from-the-sharepoint-lists-webservice/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link as well.  Access supports this functionality without having to do much ugly code.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA012337221033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So here is a sort of hack that has worked for me, no guarantees though. While your column (Office in my case) has allow multiple values enabled, fill in all of your data as needed. Once done, go to List Settings, click the Column "Office", and turn off allow multiple values. SharePoint will pop up a warning about how this data may be lost (never happened to me). Hit okay, then modify the view you want grouped, "Office" should now show up on the drop down of columns to group by. Finished result will result in your groups (and or sub groups) showing up just fine.

The only qualm I have is that instead of having an item show up in both Group A B because it had both field A and field B checked in Column X, it just creates a new group, Column X: A; B. So in my case, I have staff in both Beaufort and Orangeburg Offices, instead of having those staff in both groups (preferable) it creates a new group as below:

[image: groups]